# ER diargam for many-to-many relations

Tags: mysql, sql, database, erd

Styding DB architecture and can't understand how to build correct relations between two tables.
As I understood from articles to build relation between 2 tables we need third table - junction (join) table.

I have two variants of architecture.

First variant with PK in junction table
[ER with PK in film_rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q54b6.png)

Second var without PK and stands just with FKs:
[ER without PK in film_rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjXIW.png)

What variant is correct for developers community?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second variant, as it stands, is not entirely correct as the junction table should have a pk defined as consisting of both columns.

Given that change, neither option is right or wrong. Whether either is a better solution would depend on your own specific set of circumstances

Comment: I’ve found that one of possible solution is to perform junction primary key - use pk based on both columns ( pk film_id and pk usr_id ). 
Thx for you answer!